# Implementing a proxy between two web servers

Tags: web-services, proxy

I want to rewrite url between 2 communicating web servers, after some research i found that i had to set up a proxy to intercept URL sent from web server 1 do URL modification (in parameter passing) and resend it to web server 2. I want to generate a script to do that but i'am lost with configuring the server web 1 to pass via a proxy. any ideas about if the proxy is the right solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have any kind of control over either web server or the DNS it uses?  You could try a reverse proxy scenario if you can control server 1's DNS.  There are several proxy products that can do this, including our own product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com)

Comment: Thank you @Adrien for your comment I appreciate your interest, i just saw your message. Yes eventually i have the control of both web servers. I will try the solution of reverse proxy. is this product do treatments in URL requests sent and received?

Comment: Acctually i want to recover the URL with parameters comming from web server A, do some treatments then resend it to destination (web server B) in a script to charge in url_rewrite option in servers

Comment: It can change URLs requested, but it doesn't change hyperlinks in returned HTML content - that's a completely different scenario, but WinGate can alter the request headers and request line.